# Using vim as a filter to colorize command-line output

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I love vim's syntax highlighting. It does particularly well on unified diffs, so I use it very often like that:

```
diff -pu old new | vim -
```

I'm aware of one tip to [use vim as a better less](http://gaveen.owain.org/2009/07/syntax-highlighting-pager-vim.html), but what I really want a way to simply output colored output (no paging). I'm sure it can be done, but how?

Answer (score 5):

If you want ANSI output, I don't know of a way to accomplish that, but Vim has a :TOhtml command which I have been using in one of my Makefiles (simplified here):

```
vim -gf --noplugin -c 'if has("gui_running") | stop | endif' \
    -c 'runtime syntax/2html.vim' \
    -c 'w foo.html' -c 'qa!' foo
```

The first line where it runs "`stop`" if the GUI is running doesn't actually stop gVim, it just minimizes it.  The second line with the "`runtime`" command is basically what :TOhtml does—I don't recall any more why I chose to do it that way instead of using :TOhtml.  The third line writes "`foo.html`" and quits, and also includes the original file on the command line, which is "`foo`" in this case, and you could possibly change it to `-` instead.

Comment: + for you script. It's amazing

Comment: A comment to "I don't recall any more why I chose to do it that way instead of using :TOhtml", perhaps you didn't want to load all plugins. If you use `TOhtml` instead you have to remove `--noplugin`.

Comment: @244an: You're right. That's almost certainly the reason.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I can't comment the question, this is why I write an answer and hope that a more privileged user converts my entry to a comment.

For the usage of diff, you can also try something like:

```
svn diff |colordiff
```

colordiff does a great job by coloring diff output, maybe you give it a try for this specific situation. Otherwise, Heptite's answer is the correct approach.